# Stuck in extraction mission after killing all aliens and bringing VIP to SkyRanger

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I seem to be stuck in an extraction mission (rescuing some general) after (seemingly) killing all aliens and bringing the VIP to the SkyRanger (to the marked area).

I think I killed all the aliens, but there may be some others hidding somewhere. I've swept the area twice but could not find the missing aliens. That happened quite a bit on the original 1994 game, but I thought I read somewhere that the developers got rid of this situation in the latest version somehow.

I'm in mid-game playing in normal difficulty (no ironman mode) and the PS3 version. The mission is in Brasilia, Brazil.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the roofs?

Comment: After a few turns of no aliens this game usually lets you "hear" them, which is probably what you mean by the developers getting rid of this situation. If you're not seeing any of the "sound waves" for a few turns, then I have no suggestions apart from reloading from before the mission :-(

Comment: I'm pretty sure extraction missions are supposed to terminate the moment the extractee is in the safe zone.

Comment: @Shadur they don't if there are still aliens alive. Which is silly, because the objective has been achieved, but apparently HQ requires some more corpses to store ;-)

Comment: @Shadur see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94318/can-i-abandon-an-escort-mission-after-evacuating-the-vip-somehow?rq=1

Comment: Ah. I usually set up my people in ambush positions to intercept each new group of incoming aliens when the VIP moves to a new checkpoint, so by the time he gets to extraction there generally weren't any more aliens coming, guess that's where I got it wrong. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, during my sweeps I wasn't going near the jump point of one Thin Man. Since he wasn't on the map, he wasn't making any noises either. Once I got near that point, the last Thin Man just sprang out of nowhere, as usual, and I nailed him with a plasma rifle. That ended the mission as the VIP was already waiting at the extraction point.